# Cannot set height of a section dynamically | React

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

I am trying to set dynamic height of a component returned in react. I am using tailwind css. The code has a variable and I am trying to assign the same variable to the css value. I am also checking the height of a section using `useEffect` to print and cross verify the assigned value as well as height of the section.

**Returned component code is as follows :**

```
    <section id='homeRootSection' className={'grid min-h-['+ availableHeight +'px] bg-slate-800'} >
      <article id='homeGridArticleLeft'>
       <p>article 1</p>
      </article>
      <article id='homeGridArticleRight'>
      <p>article 2</p>
      </article>
      <article className='min-w-screen h-16 text-white relative bottom-0 left-0 right-0'>
        <p>Footer</p>
      </article>
    </section>
```

**The variable and useEffect is declared inside the component function as follows :**

```
const availableHeight = window.innerHeight;
useEffect(() => {
  const section = document.getElementById('homeRootSection');
  if (section) {
    console.log('avilable height : '+availableHeight);
    console.log('Section Height: ' + section.clientHeight);
  }
}, []);
```

This allows to cross verify the available height and the section height. However, while running the code, i am getting different values. For eg. Available height as 889 and section height as 214.

**Edit**
**Difference between other question and mine**

While it is true that string interpolation must be avoided according to docs. The main question is string interpolation is working somewhere else and not in this particular case.

Take this code,

```
<div className={"nav-header align-mobile bg-[var(--color-menu-gray)] rounded-s-full z-0 transition-transform transform " + (!isClosed ? "translate-x-full" : "translate-x-10")}>
```

In above code, classes does change when `isClosed` is changed. On top of that If i assign a static value to `availableHeight` then it works without a problem.

```
const availableHeight = 700;
<section id='homeRootSection' className={'grid min-h-['+ availableHeight +'px]'} >
```

The above code will work without any problem. Not just with value '700' but any given numeric value. For example '554', '2' , '1024'. Any static numeric value is getting assigned to the section.

My logic is, screen size will be same in full screen mode in any single device. So once the size is calculated using `window.innerHeight` the value of the variable is not changing. So,

1. Calculate height
2. Assign to variable
3. Assign to section.

This is how it should work. But, using `window.innerHeight` is not working and any static numeric value is working without any problem. Why is that?

My ultimate goal is to set the section height as the available screen height. So for different screens, the height will be different automatically. So, suppose if the available height is 889 then no matter what, the section height should be 889 too.

Comment: I am afraid not. It's a different question.

Comment: Could you provide a [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) on your second example, *The above code will work without any problem. Not just with value '700' but any given numeric value.*?

Comment: @RubenSmn Thanks for your comment. After writing code in codesandbox and codepen I realized that the code was not working there. So, I updated all the browsers I am using as well as I updated the dependencies. So now the code is not working in my pc as well, making it as the same question. I apologize for the mistake from my end.

Comment: Don't apologize, this is a moment of learning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using the `style` attribute instead, like:

```
<section
  id='homeRootSection'
  className="grid bg-slate-800"
  style={{ minHeight: availableHeight }}
>
```

Comment: While this is correct, this is not the problem in my case. I have other code where interpolating strings work. You may be correct but my question is if  the variable is assigned a constant value, it works. Take this as an example.  `const availableHeight = 889;` `<section id='homeRootSection' className={'grid min-h-['+ availableHeight +'px]'} >` in this case the section will be assigned 889px of height without problem. But won't work with `const availableHeight = window.innerHeight`.

Comment: You have `min-h-[889px]` as an unbroken string somewhere in your code base that Tailwind scans that generates the corresponding `min-h-[889px]` rule. This makes the aforementioned string interpolation work by coincidence. Or, there is some other CSS giving the element `889px` height which would be again, coincidence.

Comment: There is no other css that is making it work by coincidence. There is no literally other css in project. This is just the start and there are no other css. The question is updated. Please take a second look

Comment: Either way, my answer still stands regarding the fact that you cannot build Tailwind classes using string interpolation/concatenation (when *not* using the CDN, but that is not recommended to be used in production anyway) – consider using the `style` attribute instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After writing code in codesandbox and codepen I realized that the code was not working there. So, I updated all the browsers I am using as well as I updated the dependencies. So now the code is not working in my pc as well, making it as the same question. I apologize for the mistake from my end. I have closed the question.